# How to link my URL to a specific channel (button)from a third party widget

Tags: html

I am trying to link a channel from a third party widget to my website URL(link with a button). I need the channel to open specifically under that URL. I tried this but it is not working: 
shareurexperience  Animal https://muut.com/i/shareurexperience">shareurexperience

In other words, if one clicks on animal group on my website, www.efor-real.com, it should open the animal channel on the widget. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could enable CORS and do it through AJAX, or simply use an iframe that is updated with information from your other site depending on what is clicked.

Ex

```
$('#animal-button-id').click(function(){
   document.getElementById('iframe-id').src = 'http://url-of-animal-channel';
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will pass on the iframe. And wix does not give a lot of options when it comes to code manipulation. Just need a code that I can embed with the wix  HTML box